# Control Dual Sim Mobile Data

Tags: mobile-data, dual-sim

I recently purchased a [ChatSim](https://www.chatsim.com/) card (Chatsim mobile data is for specific messaging apps such as Messenger, Whatsapp, etc.) and they will lock your account if you use mobile data on other apps.
I have a ONEPlus 2 running android 6.0.1, OxygenOS 3.1.0 with a dual sim cards.

**So here is what I want to do:**
I would like to set only specific apps to use the Chatsim mobile data and have all other apps use my other sim cards mobile data.

1. Is there a way to control this with android system?
2. Is there an app to control this?